# I didn't find where to set up URL Aliasing to "OFF" in OpenCart

Tags: php, opencart

500 Internal Server Error occurs:
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator, support@supportwebsite.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
When I try to browser the 0.7.8 based website on amazon server the following URL address, it works.
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

I looks a URL Alias problem. But I didn't find the mod_rewrite setting on amazon server share hosting by using phpinfo(). 
I saw some similar posts, but didn't figure out how to do. Could somebody please tell me how to solve this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: You can turn SEO URL's on and off in:

Admin > System > Settings > (Your Store) > [Server Tab]

Comment: Alternatively, it's in the database - _settings table under the key `config_seo_url`